# Memory never released in android

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, out-of-memory

I read something about releasing memory in android, but I'm still confused about the behavior. In my case I test a simple application, when memory will be allocated and when it will be released. I have two activities. In MainActivity I have an ImageView. I reference a drawable image via `getResources().getDrawable(int id)` or via `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources res, int id)`. Both ways are allocating memory for the image for sure, but this memory will not be released, even if I destroy my activity, recycle the bitmap or setting all variables null.

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView view;
private Drawable drawable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    // tried with BitmapFactory.decode...
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.connect);
    view.setImageDrawable(dr);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // tried with and without finish
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Double allocated = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize())
            / new Double((1048576));
    Double available = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapSize()) / 1048576.0;
    Double free = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize()) / 1048576.0;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    System.out.println("SYSO : " + df.format(allocated) + "MB of "
            + df.format(available) + "MB (" + df.format(free) + "MB free)");
    System.out.println("SYSO : "
            + df.format(new Double(
                    Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1048576))
            + "MB of "
            + df.format(new Double(
                    Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1048576))
            + "MB ("
            + df.format(new Double(
                    Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1048576))
            + "MB free)");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // tried using BitmapFactory and bitmap.recycle()
    dr.setCallback(null);
    dr = null;
    view = null;
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}
}
```

I log the memory in my second activity, too. I found out, that my application has about 8-9MB runtime memory on start. Allocating my image in the main view, let the memory grow up to about 20MB. When I'm leaving my activity with `finish()` and using all the releasing stuff like setting callback null and recycling images, why is the memory in the second activity still allocated? I'm resuming the second activity several times and the memory is still allocated. My first activity was destroyed, how can I release its memory? I tested the behavior without setting `callback = null` or recycling bitmap and finishing the `MainActivity`. Then every time I resume the `MainActivity`, the memory grows up about 10MB per resume. Sounds OK, because the old references are not destroyed and every time a new image will be allocated. But why will this initial memory for the first image not be destroyed?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html. check this might help. also its the job of garbage collector to free memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a memory leak, first watch this very good video at google I/O 2011 about memory management -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk then after understanding about garbage collection you can try to use eclipse MAT (Memory Analyzer Tool) to find the memory leak http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

And also for bitmap I suggest you to reuse your bitmap to cache it in the memory. You can implement it like this :

```
public class MemoryCache {

    String TAG = "MemoryCache";
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private long size=0;//current allocated size
    private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

    public MemoryCache(){
        //use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit){
        limit=new_limit;
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            return cache.get(id);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        try{
            if(cache.containsKey(id))
                size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        if(size>limit){
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated  
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if(size<=limit)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap==null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

and store it like this :

```
memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
```

and check the url or URI or drawable name in your case is it existing in the cache or not before creating a new bitmap

```
WeakReference<Bitmap> bitmap = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(
                memoryCache.get(url));
```

I assume you know how to modify my code to store the cache from drawable or URI, but if you have some question about my answer, feel free to ask in the comment and if you find my answer useful don't forget to vote and accept so other people can read about this too :)

Comment: I've tried your code, but the memory from MainActivity is still allocated. I've tried to analyze it with MAT an MainActivity has still a reference, after it was destroyed by finish(). I'm wondering about the histogram in MAT. There is a FinalizeReference. It is holding a AudioManager reference and this one is holding the MainActivity. I think that this leads to my memory leak. It must be possible to free the references from MainActivity after it was destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

[histogram in MAT](http://www.dagollum.de/mat.png)

Here you can see the histogram view from MAT. I finished MainActivity and started SecondActivity. But the FinalizerReference is still holding the MainActivity. Why?